# Eloquent query not finding user by email

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to find a user form a database with 'email' = $email and send them an email. When I try to echo the $user, I receive an error that it's not a string.

```
public function sendEmail($user)
{
    Mail::to($user['email'])->Send(new VerifyEmail($user));
}

public function verifyEmail($email)
{
    $user = User::where('email',$email);

    $this->sendEmail($user ); //mail won't send

    return view('auth.email.verifyemail')->with('email', $email);
}
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: You need to specify your issue. I'ts _very_ unclear. What exactly happens? What does `$thisUser` contain? What's the class `verifyemail()` look like? Error messages? Checked you error log? Is it the database call that fails or is sending the email that fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has a few more issues than not being able to find the user, but let's address this first.

**Explanation**

Calling the `where()` method on the `User::class` is returning an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` and not the record that you are looking for.

To get a collection of records you can call fluently the `get()` method or in your case you can just get the first result by calling `first()`.

More on the topic: [Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

**Solution**

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();

if(!$user) {
  // handle the case if no user is found
}

echo $user->email // access the user's email address
```

Then you can call your sendmail method or whatever you need and pass the `$user` instance like this `$this->sendmail($user)`

Answer (score 0):

`$thisUser` has only a query. You need to execute it to get the user. Try to get the first record:

```
$thisUser = User::where('email',$email)->first();
```